# View output of previous commands

Tags: shell, terminal

Is there a way to view all the past logs such as API responses, warnings etc that displayed on the shell after closing it? Typing "history" will just show the history of commands. I need to see the past logs / everything else

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. By default, only the commands are logged.